# Writing a toString method for a nested class

Tags: java, tostring

I'm trying to write a toString() method for a class that has a inner class inside it, and I'm having trouble with that. I was thinking about looping through each array, but I didn't do it correctly. Any suggestions would be great.

```
public class MarketDataListLevel2 {

    public static class BidAskList {
        protected  MarketData Bid;
        protected MarketData Ask;
        private BidAskList(@JsonProperty("Bid") MarketData Bid, @JsonProperty("Ask") MarketData Ask) {
            this.Bid = Bid;
            this.Ask = Ask;
        }
    }

    protected BidAskList[] BidAskList;
    public MarketDataListLevel2(@JsonProperty("Top10BidAsks") BidAskList[] BidAskList) {
        this.BidAskList = BidAskList;
    }       

    public String toString() {
        // Will make an edit to this later
    }
}
```

MarketData is essentially an object with 4 fields.

EDIT:

This is the sort of data that I want outputted:

{"Top10BidAsks":[
 {"Bid":{"Price":10.0,"Size":2.0,"ExchangeID":"SMART","timeStamp":0},
  "Ask":{"Price":12.0,"Size":2.0,"ExchangeID":"SMART","timeStamp":0}},
 {"Bid":{"Price":0.0,"Size":0.0,"ExchangeID":"SMART","timeStamp":0},
  "Ask":{"Price":13.0,"Size":12.0,"ExchangeID":"SMART","timeStamp":0}}]
}

As you can see a {"Price":10.0,"Size":2.0,"ExchangeID":"SMART","timeStamp":0} is essentially 4 fields constructed from my MarketData class.

The bid and ask is essentially one object (inner class created from being made up of two Marketdata objects). And finally, the entire object is the MarketDataListLevel2 class.

Basically I want my toString method to be able to output data, that involves all 3 of these classes.

Comment: What's actually being returned as is?

Comment: Well what do you want the result to be? And why do you have both a field and a class called `BidAskList`? (Why are your fields PascalCased to start with? It would be a lot easier to read the code if you followed normal Java naming conventions.)

Comment: instance name in java should not start with capital letter

Comment: Could you be more specific than "didn't do it correctly"? I mean, we're pretty great but we can't read minds.

Comment: You're not looping through anything, so the remark that " I was thinking about looping through each array, but I didn't do it correctly" doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Sorry about that, I deleted the looping part after finding out that it didn't work. I'll add a revised version of what I did earlier in a few minutes.

Comment: voting to close as totally unclear what you're asking. fix the coding convention violations that Jon Skeet pointed out and replace BidAskList.Ask with something that makes some kind of sense, and I'll retract my close vote.

Comment: @ Nathan Yes I know that it doesn't compile, I was playing around inside my toString method and I explicitly commented that my toString method is unfinished....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you rename your inner class, BidAskList, to BidAsk. It's not really a list, but simply contains two fields of Bid and Ask. (The renaming may help some of your confusion.)

I also would suggest that you change the MarketData type to double (or float, depending on your data).

You should also name your fields (like Bid and Ask) as starting with lower case.

The following has two toString() methods. The one in the inner class prints out the BidAsk as `[45.45 x 45.47]`. The other, in the outer class, uses a foreach loop to print out each BidAsk.

```
public class MarketDataListLevel2 {

    public class BidAsk {
        protected double bid;
        protected double ask;
        private BidAsk(double bid, double ask) {
            this.bid = bid;
            this.ask = ask;
        }
        public String toString() { return "[" + bid + " x " + ask + "]"; }
    }

    protected BidAsk[] bidAskList;
    public MarketDataListLevel2(BidAsk[] bidAskList) {
        this.bidAskList = bidAskList;
    }       

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder();
        for (BidAsk bidAsk : bidAskList) {
            ans.append(bidAsk.toString());
        }
        return ans.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are quite welcome! Based on your edit, I see the four items in MarketData (price, size, exchange, and routing). I'd suggest that you change the fields in BidAsk from double back to MarketData. Add a toString() method to the MarketData class that prints out these four fields. Then change the toString() in BidAsk so that it adds the "Bid" string before the bid and the "Ask" before the ask.

Answer (score 2):

You might be overthinking this one.

An inner class by definition is something privately accessed by your class alone so in most situations you don't want any outside classes even knowing that you are using the inner class. So as others mentioned above, you don't *need* to implement a toString method for your inner class.

But if you *really* want to pass that information along you would set it up kind like an extended class in reverse... you would implement the toString in your inner class and then reference that innerClass.toString() in your outer class's toString.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
public String toString() {
        // Not finished
        return "\nMarketDataDepth:"
        + Arrays.toString(BidAskList.Ask)
        + "\n";
    }
```

This should not even compile. `BidAskList's` `Ask` field is `non-static`. Again your declaration:

```
protected BidAskList[] BidAskList;
```

confuses the statement `BidAskList.Ask`. The compiler will read `BidAskList` as an array and hence will give error : `can not find symbol : symbol variable Ask`